# How do I detect Tap and Hold on a pin in MKMapView?

Tags: mkmapview, mkplacemark

The title says it all. I'm trying to detect a tap on a pin in a `MKMapView` and I don't even know where to begin. Its not an UIView, so I can't add a gesture recognizer and I can't find a `UIView` in `MKPlaceMark` to add it.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is or you seem to have multiple questions.  Have you added the MKPlacemark to the map view as an annotation at least?  If so, why can't you use the didSelectAnnotationView delegate method to detect a tap on it?

Comment: Yes, I added it, I can't quite use that because I want to detect a HOLD not a TAP :)

Comment: You can try adding a long press gesture recognizer in the viewForAnnotation delegate method (that's where a UIView is created for an annotation).

Answer (score 1):

You're question is not very clear but you can do like this:

```
    import UIKit
    import MapKit

    protocol HandleMapSearch: class {
        func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
    }

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

       func getDirections(){

           // Here you can put anythings like:

        guard let selectedPin = selectedPin else { return }
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    }
    }

extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{       

        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        }
        pinView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()    // The pin's color
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true    // To set dialogue bubbles of the pin.

        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: smallSquare))       // To initialize the button in the dialogue bubbles of the pin.

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)    // To set and initialize the button.
        pinView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

        return pinView
    }
}
```

You can have more details in [Thorn web site](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/)